# Allow Oracle to use the synonym/SQL syntax for Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have something similar to the following statement that works in SQL-Server

```sql
-- Uses AdventureWorks    
SELECT STDEV(SalesAmountQuota) AS All_Values  
  FROM dbo.FactSalesQuota;
```

Working with Crystal Report, we want the report to support both SQL Server and Oracle. Thus, we need this statement to work in both. To get around we been wrapping functions with their other named function. I cannot get the Aggregate Function correct for STDEV (SQL-Server) to go into STDDEV(Oracle).

Any ideas on how to make this work?

STDEV to work within Oracle and provides the answer that would be returned using STDDEV aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has [*STD**D**EV*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/STDDEV.html#GUID-CA0C3B1F-1A4C-4CFB-ADAB-D90216C4E099) analytic function with a letter difference, and might be used like

```sql
WITH t(year,month,SalesAmountQuota) AS
(
 SELECT 2022,1,1000 FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2022,2,1500 FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2022,3,2000 FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2022,4,2500 FROM dual
)
SELECT STDDEV(SalesAmountQuota) OVER (ORDER BY year, month) AS StdDeviation  
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo in Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=df48edb9b8364c3134cbd9ae7facdc23)</kbd>

<kbd>[Demo in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3148ba31101f3190f67e767ec99a5422)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I need a way to use the same-named function that works for both Oracle and SQL Server to allow the same selection statement to work in both.

Comment: you're welcome @ClaytonG . They're different products and might have different dialects as in this case. You might use a conditional from your application layer to seperate the cases.

Comment: From my knowledge, Crystal Report cannot handle conditional query handling based on database type.

Comment: Hmm, well that's just a suggestion, I ain't know anything about Crystal reports @ClaytonG